# Error: function definition is not allowed here. How to correct this?

Tags: c, function, nested, nested-function, function-definition

Here is the code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

// prints I stars

void printIStars(int i) {

  // Count (call it j) from 1 to i (inclusive)

  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

    // Print a star

    printf("*");

  }

}


// prints a triangle of n stars

void printStarTriangle(int n) {

  // Count (call it i) from 1 to n (inclusive)

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    // Print I stars

    printIStars (i);

    // Print a newline

    printf("\n");

  }

}

return 0;

}
```

For both functions I get the error

> "function definition is not allowed here"

How to correct this?

Comment: C does not allow nested function definitions. Move these functions out of `main`

Comment: The function is not allowed there. How more explicit can the compiler be? Move it to somewhere where it is allowed to be.

Comment: C does not allow nested function definitions. But __gcc__ allows this as an extension, therefore your code compiles with gcc. However I recommend not to use nested functions ever, this feature is BTW not very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define both functions, `printIStars` and `printStarTriangle`, inside of the `main` function which is not permissible by each and every C implementation. GCC allows that as extension but f.e. Clang doesn't. I get the same warning for both nested function definitions when I compile your code with Clang. So, you probably use Clang or another implementation which does not support nested function definitions.

Define both functions outside of `main` which work at each implementation.

Beside this, you never called one of the functions.

So here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function prototypes.
void printIStars(int i);              
void printStarTriangle(int n);

int main (void)
{
    printIStars(4);
    puts("");         // print a newline.
    printStarTriangle(7);
    return 0;
}

// function definitions

// prints I stars
void printIStars(int i) {

  // Count (call it j) from 1 to i (inclusive)
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

    // Print a star
    printf("*");
  }
}


// prints a triangle of n stars
void printStarTriangle(int n) {

  // Count (call it i) from 1 to n (inclusive)

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    // Print I stars
    printIStars (i);

    // Print a newline
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
****
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```